# The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'. The authentication header received from the server was ' in vb.net'

Tags: .net, vb.net

Hi I am new to web service I am getting below error while passing credtials to 3rd party `WSDLlink`

> The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme
>   'Anonymous'. The authentication header received from the server was
>   ''.

```vb
Dim Cust As GetCustomer.SFDCOracleICS_GetCustomerDetail_REQUESTClient = New GetCustomer.SFDCOracleICS_GetCustomerDetail_REQUESTClient

Cust.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "UserName"
Cust.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "password"

Cust.Open()
Dim cust1 As GetCustomer.Customer = New GetCustomer.Customer
Dim PartyId As String = "100000009993101"
cust1 = Cust.GetCustomerDetails(PartyId)
Dim aa = cust1.CustomerName
Cust.Close()
```

Web.Config

```
    <binding name="ISFDCOracleICS_GetMatchOrganisation_REQUEST_binding">
      <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap11" />
      <httpsTransport />
              </binding>
    <binding name="ISFDCOracleICS_GetCustomerDetail_REQUEST_binding">
             <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap11" />
      <httpsTransport />

    </binding>

  </customBinding>
```